# How can I bloat a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Given an input matrix, is there a solution without for loops to bloat it up into a new output matrix, such that between each entry element there's `d` elements of value 0?

Example:

Input:

```
A=[[a11,a12,a13]
   [a21,a22,a23]
   [a31,a32,a33]]
d=2
```

Desired output:

```
B=[[a11, 0, 0,a12, 0, 0,a13]
   [  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0]
   [  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0]
   [a21, 0, 0,a22, 0, 0,a23]
   [  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0]
   [  0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0,  0]
   [a31, 0, 0,a32, 0, 0,a33]]
```

My way was using `numpy.zeros()` in the shape and placing the elements on their spots via 2 loops. (Well, 3 actually, because I did this for 3-dimensional arrays.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
import numpy as np

d = 3
a = np.array(
    [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]
)

b = np.zeros(np.array(a.shape) * (d + 1) - d)
b[::(d + 1), ::(d + 1)] = a  # or in general (thanks to @MadPhysicist in the comments) `b[(slice(0, None, d + 1),) * b.ndim] = a`
```

For a third dimension you could then just do `b[::(d + 1), ::(d + 1), ::(d + 1)] = a`

Comment: If you want something really magical: `b[(slice(0, None, d + 1),) * b.ndim] = a`.